# Sending variable value to other javascript file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a variable from a file called `popup.js` to another called `content.js`.

I've tried using `localStorage`, but the `content.js` file receives it as null (I am certain that the `popup.js` file declares it as string because I output its type from the popup to the console). Now, I am using `chrome.runtime` to send the variable to the `content.js`, but what I'm trying now is not giving me anything, not even any errors.

This is my `popup.js`:

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
  var amount = $('#repitions').val();
    if (amount){
      var x = JSON.stringify(amount);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({y: x});
    }
  });
});
```

And this is the section of the `content.js` file that receives the message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
    z = request;
    alert(z); 
});
```

There is something I'm doing wrong?. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of scope, there is no concept of "*files*" in JavaScript. The whole javascript code, whether is implemented in one file or 200 files runs in the same environment. There are ways to simulate namespaces or similar conepts but I don't think that's your case.

I think you can simply implement a method in the content script file and call it from your `popup.js` code, passing your variable.

Example:

- **popup.js**

```
...
$(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
  var amount = $('#repitions').val();
    if (amount){
      Content.processAmount(amount);
    }
  });
});
...
```

- **content.js**

```
var Content = {
    processAmount: function(amount){
        //do something here
        console.log(amount);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It says that Content (in the popup) is not defined

Comment: This answer is completely wrong because extensions are different: these files run in completely different processes. The content script runs in the web page whereas the popup is a separate page with a chrome-extension:// URL. See the linked duplicate topic for the correct solution.